# Can not cast imported entity in test

Tags: swift, casting, magicalrecord, xctest

I have a very simple app in Swift using Core Data. I am creating a test where I want to check that entities are properly imported from a JSON file. I am getting "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)" error when trying to do as follows:

```
let entities = SampleEntity.MR_findAll() as [SampleEntity]
let entitie = entities[0]
```

That second line is failing. It is properly working and getting the entity if I cast to [NSManagedObject] instead of [SampleEntity]. I have done this before in Objective-c and did not have such problem, but now is kind of a challenge to get it working.

I have read several other threads where people suggest to specify the app name in class field of the data model definition (e.g. "App.SampleEntity") but that is not working.

Here you can find the code for the full test:

```
import Foundation
import XCTest

class MappingTests: XCTestCase {

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()

        MagicalRecord.setDefaultModelFromClass(SampleEntity.classForKeyedArchiver())
        MagicalRecord.setupCoreDataStackWithInMemoryStore()
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        super.tearDown()

        MagicalRecord.cleanUp()
    }

    func testSampleEntitiesAreProperlyImported() {

        let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: MappingTests.classForKeyedArchiver())
        let path = bundle.pathForResource("001", ofType: "json")
        let jsonData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfFile(path!, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)
        let jsonArray = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: nil, error: nil) as NSArray

        for jsonDictionary in jsonArray {
            // This line works properly
            SampleEntity.MR_importFromObject(jsonDictionary)
        }

        let entities = SampleEntity.MR_findAll() as [SampleEntity]
        let entity = entities[0]
    }

}
```